# Check string value in enum TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

Say there is an

```
enum ArrowKey{
  Up = "ArrowUp",
  Right = "ArrowRight",
  Down = "ArrowDown",
  Left = "ArrowLeft"
}
```

Now when receiving a `KeyboardEvent` with `e.key` "ArrowUp" how is it easily checked that this string value exists in the enum? And how to pick out the right enum value afterwards?

Comment: why not use a dictionary?

Comment: Because I need the enum value to be passed into a method and this method will have a switch statement for the enum to figure out what to do next. Consider not to downvote when you have such little reputation...

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to do. You can use `e.key` directly for your switch because when `e.key === 'ArrowUp'` then `e.key === ArrowKey.Up`. You could even consider using a const enum.

Comment: First I would like to check if the string value from e.key which is "ArrowUp" exists as an enum value in the ArrowKey enum. If so, I would like to get the corresponding enum value -> ArrowKey.up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following function will return enum value corresponding to pressed arrow key or null if this key is not defined inside that enum.

```
getEnumValue(event): ArrowKey | null {
  const pressedKey = event.key;
  const keyEnum = Object.keys(ArrowKey).find(key => ArrowKey[key] === pressedKey);
  return ArrowKey[keyEnum] || null;
}
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmqwyf?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

**EDIT**: one-line equivalent (ES 2017)

```
getEnumValue(event): ArrowKey | null {
  return Object.values(ArrowKey).includes(event.key) ? event.key : null;
}
```

Comment: You might need to typecast for that second suggestion given that `event.key` is going to return a `string` not an `ArrowKey`

Comment: @jlogan you are right. Should be:

`getEnumValue(event): ArrowKey | null {
  return Object.values(ArrowKey).includes(event.key as ArrowKey) ? event.key : null;
}`